# How to set Horizontal text field in landscape mode with auto layout?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextfield

In my app i want to set text field width according screen size in landscape mode,using auto layout.it's working portrait perfectly in land scape mode not working.

Here is my Screen with auto layout,

[image]

In landscape mode showing like this,

[image]

Here is my Constraints Screen

[image]

this my View Controller

[image]

Comment: Did you set both trailing and leading space for the texview and DIDN'T set explicit width?

Comment: Remove CenterX constraint from textfields.

Comment: Please show us constraints of the textfield. Select textview, show the size inspector and take a screenshot

Comment: @RichardG removed centerX but not working same result.

Comment: @DCDC see my updated question. and width also set but not working

Comment: You have given `width = 320` and `height = 420`...it is for which view ?

Comment: @RichardG see my another screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you must have some superview under this layout that has explicit width set.

How does it look like when you tweak simulated metrics like size and orientation in your storyboard?
Alse remember to double check the view hierarchy.

Check the size inspector, your contraints should be:
trailing space to superview, leading space to superview, and some top and bottom space. And don't set explicit width value

EDIT: As you can see, the view which is the superview for your textfields and actually whole layout, has the explicitly set width value. Delete this value and instead set both trailing and leading space. This would work

Comment: exactly what width i want to delete.in my above screen shots

Comment: the width of your selected view which is inside the scroll view. This is limiting the entire layout which is the subview of it

Comment: you need to delete `width = 320` and give constraint equal width with its superview.

Comment: Exactly, this is causing the limited width of entire subview

Answer (score 1):

Constraints for scrollview - leading, trailing, top and bottom and equal width to superview.

Constraints for view inside scrollview - leading, trailing, top and bottom to scrollview and equal width to scrollview.

And the constraints given to textfields, buttons, etc. are correct. You just need to revise scrollview's and view's(inside scrollview) constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to set Centre constrain. Just set top , Leading and Trialing . so, Autolayout Adjust size automatically. check below image ,

[image]

Check Output :-

[image]

**EDIT :-**

Here i have attached Demo with Scrollview . check it.

[Constrain with scrollview](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=67896183676081291651)

Output :-

[image]

Comment: Bro there is a scrollview in asked question...and in your demonstration you didn't took scrollview.

Comment: @RichardG sorry i forgot . please check edited answer with Demo and output image.