# Mutliple UITextField with Constraints on Storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, uitextfield, constraints

I am trying to get used to AutoLayout and Constraints,

There my challenge is, I need to have six textfields following each other.

I tried to do something but its last view is as follows;

What might be the point i am missing?[image]

Comment: @Mr.Bond this is for UITextFields, there are multiple components and it is more complex than the other

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515549/how-to-give-constraints-for-uibuttons, try this one

Comment: i have 5 button instead of textfield..

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788328/how-to-set-horizontal-text-field-in-landscape-mode-with-auto-layout/36788958#36788958

Comment: @erdemgc : ever heard of Stackview :P Yes all you need is stack view :P

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment you can always make use of StackView :)

Here is how you can do it :)

First add six textfields to your view controller :)[image]

No constraint is added to any of the textfield yet :)

Now select all the textfields and stackView to them :)

[image]

After adding stack it looks like that :)

Now select any one of the textField and add a width constraint :) 
and then select all the textfileds and select Equal Width constraint :)

[image]

If you want to add equal spacing between all the textfields :) remove the width constraint on the textfield :) select the stackView [image]

Finally you will have to add the constraint to stackView itself :) Thats all :)
[image]

Final out put will look something like this :)

[image]

Hope my lengthy answer helped you :D

Comment: stackview is prior and above 9.0